# Need help to disable *:before and after

Tags: css

I am using this theme http://html5up.net/telephasic/ and trying to include http://www.sceditor.com/ script. The annoying problem is that this theme includes below code somewhere and its messing up the sceditor scripts styling and i cant find it or way to disable it for only the editor div.

I found out about the suspected code with firefox inspect plugin feature. I unticked it and editor was ok. I also used Sublime Text search feature to find it in telephasic theme folder but there were no matches in any files. The problem is on firefox and chrome.

Code

```
*, *:before, *:after { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; }
```

I am going crazy trying to disable it for specific div, hope someone can help.

Comment: You can also use !important .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
.specific-div, .specific-div:before, .specific-div:after
{
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I could swear i tried this before with no results. I guess i need some rest :)